# Picture display with PHP

Tags: php, image, gd2

I've a problem with some lines of code. I try to generate a picture with php and the gd2 librarie.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('profil.jpg');
imagejpeg($im);

imagedestroy($im);?>
```

This code doesn't work. There's no image displayed, just a message : "this image can't be displayed because there's error" displayed in white on grey background.

The picture is well loaded and "$im" is a resource created with "imagecreatefromjpeg"...

If i remove all lines except  `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');`, I've got the same problem.

Who can give me the right way ??

Thanks by advance !

Mickael

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the error message in the browser? I don't really get where the error is coming from. (Browser, PHP, GD, Apache, etc.)

Comment: maybe your image is not a real JPEG image, but a PNG or GIF one. Please do var_dump($im); before `imagejpeg($im)` this may help to debug

Comment: I've already do a var_dump of $img before "imagejpeg", It's return "Resource(3)", so "imagecreatefromjpeg" don't return FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working good after creating a new php file where I pasted my code.

I think that my file was corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Nmae that php file image.php and call it as source of image tag in another php file. Then that will show the image.

```
 <img src="image.php" height="250px" width="162px">
```

[Click Here To Download Example From Google](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-imv_uXN00BZ19VOXhfYmlqUXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thankz for your idea, but It's don't work, there's no picture displayed, like if the picture is not found on a location

Comment: It is working in my computer.Please then clear your cookie and saved files in your browser.

Comment: Did you download the example? Please download it and run it. @MOWebCreation

Answer (score -1):

I just tried your code.
The only error I get is when profil.jpg is not present in the same directory.
is profil.jpg in the same directory as your .php file ?

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask, but he wrote "'$im' is a resource". So I'm guessing the loading of the file worked just fine. Also, this is not an answer. :P

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: this is not a comment, it was a possibility that the problem was only that.

Comment: The picture is in the same folder and well loaded